# MySql, Insert data to a table row from another table row (this row is just been created)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Not sure how to describe my problem, but lets try..

I am working on a small news portal php + mysql project
I have two tables in mysql database.

```
1: news (
   n_id (primary key)
   n_title
   n_text
)

2: news_image (
   ni_id (primary key)
   n_id  (foreign key from news table)
   ni_name
   ni_caption
)
```

(n_ prefix is for new and ni_ is prefix for news_image)

news table will hold the news story and news_image table will store the names and captions for the images of the news. separate table for news images is because on later stage, i will be adding more than one images for each story. the script works fine (as i have tested it by entering data in data base through phpmyadmin.

**Problem:**
I created a php script to add data to news table and to upload images to file system. it works fine. I used this query to add row to news table

```
INSERT INTO news
SET
n_title = '$title',
n_text = '$text'
```

n_id is the primary key (integer and is AUTO_INCREMENT).. this works fine but I want a query that will execute just after the execution of above query and will automatically insert a new row in news_image table, taking n_id of the row that has just been inserted in news table. ni_name and ni_capption in news_image table is not a problem, I can get it easily but getting the n_id from news table of the newly inserted row is the problem... How can I get n_id...????? Please provide a detailed answer as I am newbie to php + mysql..
Thanks for reading...waiting for reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getting the ID of the last inserted news item? Like:

```
$lastItemID = mysql_insert_id();
```

Then you can use it to create the entry for the image:

```
INSERT INTO news_image
SET
n_id= '$lastItemID',
ni_name = '$name',
ni_caption  = '$caption'
```

Comment: Thanks... Going to try it.. should i put it just after the execution of the previous query, on the same page???

Comment: It will use the last inserted ID, no matter when and from where you call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql_insert_id();` function to get the last inserted id. Just after running the insert query use this line to get id `$id = mysql_insert_id();` and you will have the id in $id;

Comment: And what if the OP is not using the `mysql_*` extension (after all, he *shouldn't* be - and nor should you!)?

Comment: Then We can use `mysqli_insert_id();` for mysqli :)

Comment: I think mysql_insert_id() will work fine, as in my script, with all other mysql function, I have used mysql_   (e.g mysql_connect() etc)... tnaks shahzad and eggyal for help..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the PHP extension through which you're accessing MySQL - they all have `insert_id()` type functions to obtain the last auto-incremented number from the current connection.

In particular, with PDO there's [`lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) and with MySQLi there's [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).  You shouldn't be using the ancient MySQL extension, as it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).

Comment: Thanks for reply...I am using wampserver 2.2... it has MySQL Version :
5.5.20 ...    I will be helpful for me if you write a query to do so...

Comment: @JackSmithKhan: Both of the manual pages to which I linked contain examples of those functions usage.

Comment: This is very helpful, I was not expecting such quick answers.. thanks once again...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it directly in SQL with **one** querystring (I got the some problem some minutes ago :) ).

Try to shoot THIS at the database:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `news`(`n_txt`) VALUES ('Peace in Ukraine'); 
INSERT INTO `news_image`(`n_id`,`ne_name`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'smiling_merkel.jpg');"
```